Android Studio Flutter Build Fail: Failed to install the following SDK Components: Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1
I am trying to run a flutter app in Android Studio (or directly from Terminal) under Ubuntu 24.04 but i get an build Error everytime (see picture).


The first picture shows the start of the Build process where i notice that it is trying to install the Build-tools 33. Which i interessting since i am using the android sdk 35. Then it says connection refused (My internect connection is working just fine). The second picture shows the error message saying it cannot find those build-tools.
What i tried so far:
Reinstall Android Studio
Reinstall Android SDK
Reinstall Flutter SDK
Create a new Flutter Project
flutter run --stacktrace and flutter run --info doesnt exist btw. I need to build a flutter project for university. My tutor there couldnt help either. What we narrowed it down to (or we think we did) is that there must be a config file somewhere, where it secifies to use the build-tools version 33.0.1. I even tried changing the grade.build files and setting all sdk properties to the value 34 or 35 but that doesnt help either.
flutter doctor shows no problems:

The last thing i can think of is reinstalling my OS and then trying it again. But i wanted to ask for help here first and see if someone has a solution to my problem. If you need additional info just let me now :)

Please do not post terminal text output as screenshot. Just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code.

use the following settings in android/build.gradle
android {
    namespace = "com.example.abc"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = "27.2.12479018"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

gradle-wrapper.properties file -
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip

settings.gradle file -
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.7.2" apply false
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.20" apply false
}

